# Removing element attributes from XML document using Linux tools

Tags: linux, xml

I do have a file that contains lines similar to the following:

```html
<Item Name="INV_LIST" Justification="End" LowestAllowedValue="" DistanceBetweenRecords="0" Width="45" MaximumLength="12" SynchronizedItemName="INVOICE_AMT" PromptDisplayStyle="First Record"/>
<Item Name="INVOICE_AMT_LIST" Justification="End" LowestAllowedValue="" DistanceBetweenRecords="0" Width="48" MaximumLength="22" SynchronizedItemName=""  PromptDisplayStyle="First Record"/>
<Item Name="INV_LIST2" Justification="End" LowestAllowedValue="" DistanceBetweenRecords="0" Width="233" MaximumLength="12" SynchronizedItemName="INVOICE_AMT2" PromptDisplayStyle="First Record"/>
```

I want to run a Linux command like sed or awk, to remove the attribute MaximumLength and its value (it does not matter what it contains between the quotes) whenever there is a line that contains a SynchronizedItemName with a value. If the line contains SynchronizedItemName="", the line will remain untouched.

I want to end with the following:

```html
<Item Name="INV_LIST" Justification="End" LowestAllowedValue="" DistanceBetweenRecords="0" Width="45" SynchronizedItemName="INVOICE_AMT" PromptDisplayStyle="First Record"/>
<Item Name="INVOICE_AMT_LIST" Justification="End" LowestAllowedValue="" DistanceBetweenRecords="0" Width="48" MaximumLength="22" SynchronizedItemName=""  PromptDisplayStyle="First Record"/>
<Item Name="INV_LIST2" Justification="End" LowestAllowedValue="" DistanceBetweenRecords="0" Width="233" SynchronizedItemName="INVOICE_AMT2" PromptDisplayStyle="First Record"/>
```

Comment: How thorough do you want it to be? Does it have to handle attributes in single quotes as well as double quotes? Whitespace around the equals sign? Attributes separated by newlines rather than spaces? Attributes split across multiple lines? Commented-out elements? If you want to handle all possible cases, use an XML parser, not sed or awk.

Comment: In the file both attributes only carry double quotes. No newlines within a tag. One line per tag. There are no comments. The lines above have other elements removed for the sake of readability. I am interested only on removing the line occurrence of MaximumLength="XXXX" when the SynchronizedItemName contains a value. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try with this awk script:

```
{
where = match($0, "SynchronizedItemName=\"\"")
if (where != 0) print
else{
  gsub(/MaximumLength=\"[0-9]*\"/, ""); print
  }
}
```

Given your input, I get output as:

```
<Item Name="INV_LIST" Justification="End" LowestAllowedValue="" DistanceBetweenRecords="0" Width="45"  SynchronizedItemName="INVOICE_AMT" PromptDisplayStyle="First Record"/>
<Item Name="INVOICE_AMT_LIST" Justification="End" LowestAllowedValue="" DistanceBetweenRecords="0" Width="48" MaximumLength="22" SynchronizedItemName=""  PromptDisplayStyle="First Record"/>
<Item Name="INV_LIST2" Justification="End" LowestAllowedValue="" DistanceBetweenRecords="0" Width="233"  SynchronizedItemName="INVOICE_AMT2" PromptDisplayStyle="First Record"/>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Pankaj! That sort of worked. When I ran on the file I wanted to modify it ended up removing all instances of MaximuLength from all elements. However using this I managed to write something that worked. cat tempo | awk '{ ret = match($0, "SynchronizedItemName=\"[0-9A-Za-z_]+\"")
                  if (ret > 0) {
                    gsub(/MaximumLength=\"[0-9]*\"/, ""); print $0
                  }
                  else {
                    print $0
                  }
                }' > tmpo_file && mv tmpo_file tempo

Answer (score 0):

If you have xmlstarlet available, you could use the [`ed`](http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/doc/UG/xmlstarlet-ug.html#idm47077139594320) command...

NOTE: The "-L" global option modifies the file in-place. Remove this if you do not want to modify the original input file.

```
xmlstarlet ed -L -d '//Item[normalize-space(@SynchronizedItemName)]/@MaximumLength' input.xml
```

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately I don't have it and cannot get it.

Answer (score 0):

Using Pankaj code above, put it me the right track.
His code worked with the small set of lines in my example and a few others I added, but on the larger file, it replaced all the elements with MaximumLength.

However, my solution is based on his idea, so thanks Pankaj again.

Here is what I ended up with:

```
cat tempo | awk '{ ret = match($0, "SynchronizedItemName=\"[0-9A-Za-z_]+\"")
              if (ret > 0) {
                gsub(/MaximumLength=\"[0-9]*\"/, ""); print $0
              }
              else {
                print $0
              }
            }' > tmpo_file && mv tmpo_file tempo
```

The last bit (the redirection), just prints the file to a temporary one and then replaces the original.